# pgAgent scheduled job failed on Windows

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, job-scheduling, pgagent

I am trying to set up the step with Batch file path on particular time in pgAgent via pgAdmin. But when I run that it is failing and in Step statistics I got this Output

> C:\Windows\system32>C:\postgresql\run.bat
>   'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

**Details:**

```
Postgresql 9.3.5 on local system account (Current User)
pgAdmin 1.18.1
pgAgent via stack builder with Administrator account (Current User)
```

in *run.bat* I have only two statement

```
@echo off
psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -d test -a -f "test.sql"
```

I have **psql** in system path variable and able to access it in cmd. When I run that bat file manually it is executing without fail. But when I given the batch file path `(C:\postgresql\run.bat)` in pgAgent jobs it is giving that error in statistics.

Is there anything wrong in my configuration? Why it is always going to that `C:\Windows\system32>`?

**Edit:**

My *run.bat* file

```
 @ECHO OFF

SET LBSDatabaseName=Test
SET dbHost=localhost 
SET dbPort=5434 
SET dbUser=postgres 
SET logFile=DbInstall.log 
SET sqlFolder="D:\SOURCECODE\archivescripts"        

"C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe" -h "%dbHost%" -p "%dbPort%" -d "%LBSDatabaseName%" -U "%dbUser%" -L "%logFile%" -q -f "%sqlFolder%\Archive.sql"
```

My *Archive.sql*

```
update "Archive".emp set "FirstName"='Srikanth Dyapa';
```

Comment: you need to give the path where `psql` is located in your `run.bat`

Comment: show me the absolute path to your `psql`(in my case its `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe`)

Comment: @WingedPanther I tried your suggestion, now i am seeing its status as Running, its not updating the table records, what could be the problem?

Comment: probably within that `test.sql` ! does your `bat` file executing correctly ??

Comment: @WingedPanther when i run the bat file, i am seeing the record change in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example,

> D:\pgAgent_jobs

is the path where `psql` located.

> D:\pgAgent_jobs\scripts\test.sql

is the path in which my `test.sql` placed.

> D:\pgAgent_jobs\scripts\psqlss.bat

is my *bat* file to execute `test.sql`

so my *bat* file will be like below

```
 @echo off

cd /D D:\\pgAgent_jobs

psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d db_name -a -f "D:\pgAgent_jobs\scripts\test.sql"
```

---

Note : my pg_hba.conf is configured with `trust` for all `hosts` that's why am not passing any `password` in the above `psql` command

Comment: I updated my question as per your suggestion, but now it is in Running state but not updating the table records, Can you help me to identify the issue....

Comment: @DyapaSrikanth are you sure that your update is correctly running ??

Comment: a suggestion >  add an additional line `pause` in your  `run.bat` (last line)   and run that bat file manually (just double click)

Comment: can you see that the things you wrote in your `.sql` in the console ??

Comment: Finally after replacing `pgsql,.sql` with exact location it is working, and also I modified the `METHOD` in pg_hba.conf with `trust` because my `pgpass.conf` contains plain passwords. Even though query executed fine, Job status showing `Failure`, may be it is a bug in pgAgent.